# foreach loop to read element in an array with three users

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm just learning PHP and I'm stuck at this question.

> use foreach loop to read element in an array with three users information

so I did this so far

```
$person = array (
  "first_name" => "Carlos",
  "last_name"  => "Leon",
  "address"    => "630 west 139 street",
  "city"       => "New York",
  "zip_code"   => "11364"
);

foreach ($person as $attribute =>$data ){
  $attr_nice =ucwords ($attribute);
  $attr_nice =str_replace ("_" , " ", $attr_nice);
  echo "$attr_nice = $data <br/>";
}
```

Whats next? How can I do the three users?

Comment: Have you encountered nested arrays yet?

Comment: not yet, this is the update that i got now

$person = array (

"first_name" => array("Carlos" "john", "peter"),

 "last_name"  => array("Leon", "wooh", "lopes"),

 "address"    => array("address user 1", "address user 2, address user 3"),

 "city"       => array("Bayside", "fresh meadows", "New York"),

"zip_code"   => array("23246", "11364", "20100", "11235")

);

foreach ($person as $attribute => $data){

echo $attribute . $data[2];

echo "<br/>"
}

How can I loop it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the additional data you received. Thanks!

Comment: @TinyTim - Greg's answer below demonstrates nested arrays.

Answer (score 1):

To create a nested array, you want something like this:

```
$people = array(
    array(
        "first_name" => "Carlos",
        "last_name"  => "Leon",
        "address"    => "630 west 139 street",
        "city"       => "New York",
        "zip_code"   => "11364"
    ),
    array(
        "first_name" => "...",
        "last_name"  => "...",
        "address"    => "...",
        "city"       => "...",
        "zip_code"   => "..."
    ),
);
```

Then do a `foreach ($people as $person) { }` and your original code can go inside this loop.

Answer (score 0):

You may put $person in another array too.

1. Create 3 person in respective variable.
2. Add 3 person in a arrayA.
3. Create first loop to iterate arrayA.
4. Create second loop inside first loop to iterate each person.

Comment: i added the arrays to all the people how do i loop it